# MySql join with IN clause not working

Tags: mysql, date, join

i'd like to join two tables with a IN clause but results are not right.

Table one just has some "bookings" and in one field i'm storing the ids of dates they should be linked to. So my rows are like:

```
id_booking 1
days 1,2,3,4

id_booking 2
days 1,2
```

Table 2 contains for each "ID_DAY" the date as follows:

```
id_day 1
date 2017-10-01

id_day 2
date 2017-10-02

id_day 3
date 2017-10-03

id_day 4
date 2017-10-04
```

bookings:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings ( id_booking int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, days varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_booking) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

days:

```
CREATE TABLE days ( id_day int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_day) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, my idea was doing something like:

```
select * from bookings join days on days.id_day in (bookings.days);
```

This always returns one row, not N rows as i would expect. How can i get to my result?

My problem begins with having to find a way to have a single table with all the days of the year and then joining that to the bookings table, in order to have "N ROWS" for each booking, so i can filter on dates, counting them or doing operations, but i can't find a smart way to achieve this.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Please post the exact table structure and expected result.

Comment: bookings:

CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id_booking` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `days` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_booking`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


days:

CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `id_day` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


query:

select * from bookings join days on days.id_day in (bookings.days);

i'm expecting N rows for each day, not just one. I can't figure out formatting

Comment: You can try this query for your problem : `Select bookings.*, GROUP_CONCAT(days.date ORDER BY days.id_day) as days From bookings 
LEFT JOIN days on FIND_IN_SET(days.id_day, bookings.days) > 0`

Comment: no, i want N booking rows, not one booking row with concatenated dates. i explained i need this way in order to filter dates if necessary

Comment: it works like this select * from bookings join days on  FIND_IN_SET(days.id_day, bookings.days); but it's horrendously slow on a big table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Why you are storing comma separated values in a column. This violates the 1NF rule. Please try to avoid storing `,` separated fields into a column.

The query you are using is returning 2 rows -

```
id_booking  days    id_day      date
1           1,2,3,4 1           2017-10-01
2           1,2     1           2017-10-01
```

Comment: how can i avoid doing this? I'd like a table with bookings but i also need to filter the bookings (like for a hotel you have a checkin date, a checkout date but i want to filter on all the dates in between the two).
I can't come up with a solution for this without having a second table with a million rows (each id booking is a key in a "days table" with every day between the checkin and checkout).

Comment: well this is embarrasing. I think you are experiencing the [XY][1] problem :) 
If you tell us the real problem, you might get a sleek answer :) [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: it seems like no one ever faced this problem..
the problem is as explained: i have a table with bookings. They have a start and end date. I have another table with every day of each booking (1 booking = N rows, one per day). The two tables have in common one key: the id booking. Every time i need to filter results i have to join the two tables but if these are HUGE, it takes A LOT of time (to me a lot is 2 seconds). I need to find another way to do this without losing much time, trying to ask for this.